# gzserver error while loading shared libraries

Tags: software-installation

I installed Gaebo 1.9 under Ubuntu 12.04, but it did not work with ros hudro, so I uninstalled it.

Now I am trying to reinstall it following [these](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/1.9/install#Pre-compiled_binaries) instructions. When I enter the command

```
sudo apt-get install gazebo
```

I get:

```
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 581 not upgraded.
```

When I try to launch `gzserver` I get:

```
gzserver: error while loading shared libraries: libsdformat.so.1:
     cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.
```

Answer (score 0):

To completely reinstall it use:
`sudo apt-get purge gazebo` then `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install gazebo`.

Then try to launch it again with `gzserver`.

Comment: i tryed that but is still not working

Comment: Still the same error as above?

Comment: yes the error message

Comment: Have you done an update before installing? If not do `sudo apt-get update`.

Comment: of course i did the update before installing

Comment: i am tryin now : sudo apt-get dist-upgrade we will see if it will work .

Comment: If it does not work you can compile the program yourself instead of using the ppa. That will work.